# iPhone invoking a Objective-C from Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

How to invoke a Objective-C method from Javascript without a UIWebview.

Comment: Without a UIWebView? Where's your javascript running?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to port and include your own Javascript interpreter if you don't want to use a UIWebView.

Comment: And this would be against the App Store rules if you used it on scripts that are not bundled with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try libraries like JSCocoa: http://inexdo.com/JSCocoa